# Calculating user karma with acts_as_votable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I using the `acts_as_votable` gem: https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable

There are three votable models

1. Comments
2. Books
3. Movies

Each of these models belongs to a user.

A users karma would be the total votes received on all of their comments, books, and movies, times a 2 plus the score adjustment value.

Right now i'm trying this with just the comments:

```
<%= "#{((current_user.comments.map{|c| c.votes.count}.inject(:+))*2) + current_user.score_prop}" %>
```

And i'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass
```

I just keep on running into error after error with this. What's the best way to calculate the total score based on the comments, books, and movies? Should I be doing this from my controller instead of my view? (the reason I have it in the view is because I have this in the footer layout.

Comment: I'm guessing this is exploding when the current user has no comments? or the comments have no votes - either way there is a nil and you are calling inject on it... which will of course not work.

Comment: btw - `<%=` already calls "to_s" - you don't need to put your calculation inside of a string: `"#{}"`

Comment: I'm using the string interpolation to add text around the outputted number, and yup, your right!! It's when the user has no votes or comments that this thing goes crazy!!! :)

Comment: Yeah - you need to check for that sort of thing before continuing with your calculation. See my answer

Comment: Fair enough re: string interpolaion - though it's useful if you strip out that kind of thing in your Stack Overflow question - as it's unnecessary to us help you solve your problem for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= "#{((current_user.comments.map{|c| c.votes.count}.inject(:+))*2) + current_user.score_prop}" %>
```

so first up, `<%=` already calls `to_s` - you don't need to put your calculation inside of a string: `"#{}"`

```
<%= ((current_user.comments.map{|c| c.votes.count}.inject(:+))*2) + current_user.score_prop %>
```

secondly, `sum` exists and is vastly easier to understand than `inject` so it's better to use it where you can:

```
<%= ((current_user.comments.map{|c| c.votes.count}.sum)*2) + current_user.score_prop %>
```

finally, lets strip out the parts. That lets us see *which* part of your long calculation is the bit that's breaking
Try this and see if any line now breaks:

```
<% comment_vote_count = current_user.comments.map{|c| c.votes.count}.sum
   # I've added this as my best guess for what will fix your problem
   comment_vote_count ||=0 

   comment_vote_count *= 2
   total_vote_count = comment_vote_count + current_user.score_prop %>
<%= total_vote_count %>
```

Now once you get it all working - you can put the code back into one line again - it's just good to split this stuff out when something is wrong and you can't figure out which bit is breaking.

Comment: I'm getting this error: undefined local variable or method `coment_vote_count' for #<#<Class:0x0000011613a238>:0x00000101561d80>

Comment: that's because there's a typo (now fixed)

Comment: yeah - you should only do this if you're signed in - otherwise current_user is nil.

Comment: Yup, sorry about that, just added that, works like a charm! :))))))

Comment: Hey Taryn! Could you take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096134/threading-on-polymorphic-comments

Comment: Looks like I don't need to any more - you have an answer :)