# Threading on polymorphic comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've setup two models that are commentable through same comments table:

My comments schema:

```
  create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "commentable_id"
    t.string   "commentable_type"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

My comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_votable
end
```

My movie model

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

My book model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

My comments controller:

```
def index
  @commentable = find_commentable
  @comments = @commentable.comments
end

def create
  @commentable = find_commentable
  @comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment])
  @comment.user = current_user
  if @comment.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created comment."
    redirect_to @commentable
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end

  def upvote_movie
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
  @comment = @movie.comments.find(params[:id])
  @comment.liked_by current_user

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to :back}
  end
end


  def upvote_book
  @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
  @comment = @book.comments.find(params[:id])
  @comment.liked_by current_user

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to :back}
  end
end


private

def find_commentable
  params[:commentable_type].constantize.find(params[:commentable_id])
end
end
```

How can I add threading(reply to comments) to what I already have?

Here is a blog that talks about threading:http://www.davychiu.com/blog/threaded-comments-in-ruby-on-rails.html

I'm just not sure how to put the two together.

Here is what I have in my movie show view:

```
<%= render partial: "comments/form", locals: { commentable: @movie } %>


<% @comments.each do |comment| %>

<hr>
  <p>
   <strong><%= link_to comment.user.username, user_path(comment.user), :class => "user" %>
</strong> <a><%= "(#{time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at)} ago)" %></a>
  </p>

  <p>

    <%= simple_format(auto_link(comment.body, :html => { :target => '_blank' } )) %>
<% end %>
```

Here is what my comment form looks like:

```
<%= form_for [commentable, Comment.new] do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :commentable_type, commentable.class.to_s %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :commentable_id, commentable.id %>
  <p>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I scanned the article you mentioned and found the solution there is quite limited.

The basic idea in the article is to set a comment itself as commentable. So a nested comment is actually NOT a comment of the post, but of the parent comment.

The drawbacks are apparent and unacceptable:

1. It's hard to get other things right. For example, `posts.comments.size` is no long correct.
2. You'll have hard dependency on this structure. If in one day you don't want to display comments in thread but plainly, you...will kick a stone.
3. If you want to do it on current comment system, it's hard.

#### Actually a simple solution could solve the problem:

1. Add an extra field `reply_to` to comment model, referring to other comment's id.
2. When adding comment, add a `reply_to` id if it replied to one.
3. When showing, show a list of all comments with `reply_to` null.
4. Then for each comment, show nested comments has its id. And do it recursively.
5. If you want to limit the nested level, you can add an extra `nested_level` field, getting in from the front-end. If nest limit is 3, no comments is allowed to reply a comment with nest level of 3.

**add: demo helper to render recursively**

```
def render_replied_comments(comment)
  if comment.has_reply
    comments.replies.each do |reply|
      render partial: 'comment', locals: {comment: reply}
      render_replied_comment(reply)
    end
  end
end

# View
@post.top_level_comments.each do |comment|
  render partial: 'comment', locals: {comment: comment}
end
```

Comment: Thanks Billy, can we continue this in a chat box thingy?

Comment: Kaitie, my pleasure if the answer helps a bit. Sorry I'll leave soon so I can't chat. You can post new question if new problems found when you code the idea.

Comment: I just added an edit to the question showing what my form and show view looks like. How do I implement what you're describing?

Comment: Should the comments be rendering through a partial?

Comment: Katie, yes it's better in a partial and the rendering are better be within a helper so nested calling is easier. I'm afraid the implementation would be a bit hard if you are new to Rails. I have added a demo helper about the idea of recusive rendering. Take it slowly, you can start with other simple feature at first.

Comment: Thank you sooo much, your right, as a newbie, this is confusing the heck out of me :((

Comment: Can you let me know if you have time to jump in a chatbox later? I tried a bunch of things, and am getting some errors.

Answer (score 0):

You would add a parent_id to the comments model that is a self-referencing relationship. So parent comments would have a parent_id of nil and all child comments would have a parent_id of that parent comment. You are essentially constructing a tree.

The [Ancestory Gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) is ideal for this or roll your own, good learning experience.